# 404 Error for HTTP to HTTPS Redirect Rule

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, redirect

I'm getting the below error for our root domain and all subsites when they are typed in the format http://domain.co.uk or https://domain.co.uk

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

We're running Windows Server 2012R2 and I'm editing the web.config file, rather than using IIS.

I've got the below redirect in place, but obviously it isn't doing what I'd like it to do.

```
<rule name="Force WWW and SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.domain.co.uk/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know where I'm going wrong.